# Pyramid Exercise java is not perfectly aligned

Tags: java, algorithm

> Write  a GraphicsProgram subclass  that  draws  a  pyramid  consisting
>   of  bricks arranged  in  horizontal  rows,  so  that  the  number  of 
>   bricks  in  each  row  decreases  by one as you move up the pyramid

This is my code:

```
import acm.graphics.GRect;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;

public class Pyramid extends GraphicsProgram {
public void run() {

    int BRICK_WIDTH = 30;
    int BRICK_HEIGHT = 12;
    int BRICKS_IN_BASE = 20;

    for (int i = 1; i <= BRICKS_IN_BASE; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {

            add(new GRect(this.getCanvasWidth() / 16 + (BRICK_HEIGHT * i)
                    + BRICK_WIDTH + (BRICK_WIDTH * (BRICKS_IN_BASE - j)),
                    BRICK_HEIGHT * i, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT));

        }

    }

}
}
```

if BRICK_WIDTH is 30 and BRICK_HEIGHT is 12 the pyramid is not aligned perfectly,
but it is aligned perfectly if the brick_width is 30 and brick_height is 15.

This is a screenshot of the pyramid if BRICK_WIDTH is 30 and BRICK_HEIGHT is 12[image]
This is a screenshot of the pyramid if BRICK_WIDTH is 30 and BRICK_HEIGHT is 15[image]

Comment: Please read [How To ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page carefully and apply those rules to your question.

Comment: Probably because your line `add(new GRect(this.getCanvasWidth() / 16 + (BRICK_HEIGHT * i)` needs to read `add(new GRect(this.getCanvasWidth() / 16 + (BRICK_WIDHT / 2 * i)`  - and if BRICK_HEIGHT equals 15 and BRICK_WIDTH is 30, then `BRICK_HEIGHT * i == (BRICK_WIDHT / 2 * i)`

Comment: Need to much guess-work to answer the question. Please post [mcve]

Comment: Erwin Bolwidt thank you for the response. It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound logical to use the BRICK_HEIGHT to determine the x coordinate of your GRect.

You need to change your line

```
add(new GRect(this.getCanvasWidth() / 16 + (BRICK_HEIGHT * i)
```

To

```
add(new GRect(this.getCanvasWidth() / 16 + (BRICK_WIDTH / 2 * i)
```

It works if `BRICK_HEIGHT` equals 15 and `BRICK_WIDTH` is 30, because then `BRICK_HEIGHT * i == (BRICK_WIDHT / 2 * i)`.

But in general, you want your base x coordinate for drawing the current line to be based on the width of the brick, not on the height.